# Из-за чего падает производительность gulp?

Tags: gulp

На маленьких проектах проблем не было. Проблемы начались после крупных проектов (верстка), через минут 20 - 30 начинает долго преобразовывать из-за чего ожидаю долго пока появятся изменения в браузере
Это мой gulpfile.js (собирал по крупицам из разных источников):

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    newer = require('gulp-newer'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprites'),
    svgmin = require('gulp-svgmin'),
    cheerio = require('gulp-cheerio'),
    replace = require('gulp-replace'),
    create = browserSync.create(),
    reload = browserSync.reload;

var path = {
        build: { //Тут мы укажем куда складывать готовые после сборки файлы
            html: './build/',
            js: './build/js/',
            css: './build/css/',
            img: './build/img/',
            maps: '../maps/',
            fonts: './build/fonts/'
        },
        src: { //Пути откуда брать исходники
            html: './src/*.html', //Синтаксис src/*.html говорит gulp что мы хотим взять все файлы с расширением .html
            js: './src/js/*.js',//В стилях и скриптах нам понадобятся только main файлы
            style: './src/style/*.scss',
            img: './src/img/**/*.*', //Синтаксис img/**/*.* означает - взять все файлы всех расширений из папки и из вложенных каталогов
            fonts: './src/fonts/**/*.*'
        },
        watch: { //Тут мы укажем, за изменением каких файлов мы хотим наблюдать
            html: './src/**/*.html',
            js: './src/js/**/*.js',
            style: './src/style/**/*.scss',
            img: './src/img/**/*.*',
            fonts: './src/fonts/**/*.*'
        },
        clean: './build'
    },
    config = {
        server: {
            baseDir: "./build"
        },
        tunnel: false,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 9005,
        logPrefix: "frontend",
        devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost'
    };

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    browserSync(config);
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.html) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
        .pipe(rigger()) //Прогоним через rigger
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true})); //И перезагрузим наш сервер для обновлений*/
});

gulp.task('img:build', function (cb) {
    gulp.src(path.src.img) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
        .pipe(newer(path.build.img))
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img))//Выплюнем их в папку build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true})); //И перезагрузим сервер
});

gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.js) //Найдем наш main файл
        .pipe(rigger()) //Прогоним через rigger
        .pipe(uglify()) //Сожмем наш js
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js)) //Выплюнем готовый файл в build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true})); //И перезагрузим сервер
});

gulp.task('style:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.style) //Выберем наш main.scss
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'expanded'
        }).on('error', sass.logError)) //Скомпилируем
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css)) //И в build
        .pipe(rename({
            prefix: "",
            suffix: ".min",
            extname: ".css"
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer()) //Добавим вендорные префиксы
        .pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}, function (details) {//Сожмем
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.originalSize);
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.minifiedSize);
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(path.build.maps, {
            addComment: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css)) //И в build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('fonts:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts))
});

gulp.task('build', [
    'html:build',
    'js:build',
    'style:build',
    'fonts:build',
    'img:build'
]);

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch([path.watch.html], function (event, cb) {
        gulp.start('html:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.style], function (event, cb) {
        gulp.start('style:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.js], function (event, cb) {
        gulp.start('js:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.fonts], function (event, cb) {
        gulp.start('fonts:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.img], function (event, cb) {
        gulp.start('img:build');
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

**Мой package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Gulp frontend",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "Alex Lenk",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower-installer": "^1.2.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-cheerio": "^0.6.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.10",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-rigger": "^0.5.8",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-svg-sprites": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-svgmin": "^1.2.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.8",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "0.0.28"
  }
}
```

Comment: такое бывает часто и чем вызвано не понятно. Много раз искал в гугле и спрашивал и никто ответа не давал. Возможно, это утечки или особенность `node`. Вот почему после перезагрузки компа первый запуск `gulp` очень долгий, но если завершить работу, закрыть консоль и снова запустить `gulp`, то скомпилирует уже намного быстрее? Значит где-то есть хеш, который возможно и создается постоянно и не удивлюсь, если он течет. Хотя самое интересное диспетчер не фиксирует жор памяти, просто все тупит.  Это я сказал для того, чтобы Вы не получив ответа, не переживали что только у Вас так, так у многих.

Comment: Самое печально то , что и лечить это дело достаточно сложно. Я так и не нашел способа это починить. Одни грешат на browserSync, другие на еще какие модули.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Парни, я долго искал в чем проблема и все таки нашел! Все дело в модуле chokidar который использует gulp.watch, вам нужно активировать usePolling: true.
https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar

Пример:

watch('path/to/file.*', {usePolling: true}, gulp.series('task');

Comment: Ничего, что в вопросе он не упоминается?

Comment: Спасибо, в моем случае помогло, раньше ждать приходилось около минуты. Вообще думал уже менять сборщик.

Answer (score 0):

В моем `gulpfile.js` получилось так:

```
     function watchFiles(params) {
gulp.watch([path.watch.html], {usePolling: true}, gulp.series('html'))
gulp.watch([path.watch.css], {usePolling: true}, gulp.series('css'))
gulp.watch([path.watch.js], {usePolling: true}, gulp.series('js'))
gulp.watch([path.watch.img], {usePolling: true}, gulp.series('images'))
gulp.watch([path.watch.fonts], {usePolling: true}, gulp.series('fonts'))
}
```